# Where to store the values of coins and experience points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please tell me where you need to store coins and experience points, for example, I have passed the level I am credited with both coins and points, I want to add them with the values that I already have. Do I need to create a class with static variables where they will be stored or create a table with points in the database (SQLITE) where each user will have the number of coins and experience points?

Answer (score 1):

Use PlayerPrefs:

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coin", coin); // e.g set data

var loadCoin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin"); // e.g load data
```

Comment: And where to define it in scripts? that is, for example, when the user logs in, he sees that he has a certain number of coins?

Comment: @AvgustKuk When saving, if you want to save immediately after gaining points, you can add it after changing the amount of coins. For load either during the Start Game Scene or when you hit the load button.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class `LevelRewardConfig`

```
    public class LevelRewardConfig
    {
         public int coins;
         public int exp;
    }
```

And another class which store a list of `LevelRewardConfig`, it can be `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: And if a player wants to hack and add more coins to himself, is it possible to protect these classes?

Comment: @AvgustKuk I mean if your coins per level are **Fixed** then you could store it in your build with Scriptable Object then user cannot be able to change it.